# My printer is making mistakes on the right half of the print, but not the left

Tags: troubleshooting, monoprice-maker-select

I am an absolute beginner having issues with my Monoprice Maker select v2 printer. 
The left half of my prints look fine but the right half always gets messed up. When I watch it print the right half of an object it seems that the PLA isn't sticking even though I level the bed thoroughly beforehand. I don't think the problem is that the right half of my board is not sticky enough, because when I move the print so that the whole thing prints on the left half of the bed the problem persists.

I have attatched a photo to show what I am talking about. Any help is appreciated

Edit: I'm using inland pla. The extruder is at 220° and the bed temp is 60°
[image]

Comment: Looks like bed isn't leveled.

Comment: And in need of some glue or spray to adhere it better. You could try even better levelling and increase bed temperature. Please post temperatures.

Comment: unlevel bed and a dirty bed.

Comment: @Trish is it possible that my bed is dirty after just one print? I've only had it for a week or two.

Comment: if you touch it with your fingers, you might leave grease, which can impact the adhesion. However, it should be a mechanical thing. For new machines I suspect either an unlevel bed or an X-beam out of position. Note that 220°C for PLA is WAY too hot. At that tempoerature PLA gets super runny and doesn't properly stick. Go down to 200°C and try again.

Comment: @Trish: I use 215 for first layer with PLA, 210 after that. 220 is on the high end but doesn't seem extreme.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. This model of printer Monoprice Select v2 has bed warping issues so when the bed heated up it would warp severely. I bought a glass bed and all my problems were solved.

Answer (score 0):

- Try cleaning bed with isopropyl alcohol to remove grease from the bed. (increases stickyness)
- Try increasing bed temp to 70°C (increases stickyness)
- If this is not enough, do a fresh bed leveling.